# HTML un-styled is shown first and then changes to styled version, what could cause this?

Tags: css, loading

It doesn't always happen so it makes me think it happens when the browser doesn't have the css cached. What happens is the page loads and you see the entire page without any css and then it "pops" in styled. The css files are hosted off a different domain and they're all in the header of the document. Any thoughts?

Browser around the source I noticed that we have google optimizer code on some pages. Could this cause this to happen?

Comment: I thought browsers didn't render until all css files were downloaded?

Comment: "FOUC" (flash of unstyled content) is what you should be searching for to find more information. Without a link to your page, all people can do is guess what could be causing it. Also, which browser(s) are you testing this in?

Comment: Maybe you are using `@import` inside `STYLE` element. Use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" />` instead.

Comment: That's up to the browser. Most start displaying the content even while loading the external resources. I presume it depends on how long it takes to load stuff. Letting the user stare at a completely white screen for many seconds, just because one silly little graphic won't load, is a no-no. Users would conclude that the browser was unacceptably slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be many reasons, behind this, but as you described:

> Your CSS are not included in inside the `<head>`

Comment: @RyanDetzel, are the stylesheet, pretty heavy?

Comment: @RyanDetzel, SO that's the problem. Filter the CSS only needed for the active page to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Is this perhaps a [flash of unstyled content](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content).